# Excel: How jump columns in table from command text?

Tags: excel

[image]

How can I skip columns H and I and get column L? Getting something like for example: `Cargos$A:G;L`

This example doesn't work...

Comment: index() with match() ?

Comment: @SolarMike I believe that it is not possible to use formulas in the formulary of the image.

Comment: Multiple ranges works for chart concatenating the ranges using `,`may be it works for your connection

Comment: @DavidLeal I tried "Cargos$A:H,J:L" and dont work. =/